# ¿Como llenar datatable desde sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatables

quiero llenar un datatable desde sql server tengo esto pero me manda un error:
"Cannot find column 0."

```
 DataTable Dt = new DataTable();
 if(readercoti.Read())
 {
 DataRow dr = Dt.NewRow();
 dr[0] = readercoti[21].ToString();
 dr[1] = (byte[])readercoti[14];
 Dt.Rows.Add(dr);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probablemente sea porque creaste tu DataTable sin ninguna columna. Te dejo este fragmento de código que he utilizado anteriormente para cargar datos en un DataTable, espero te sea de utilidad y lo puedas adaptar a tu caso particular.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("NombreDelDataTable"); //Creamos el DataTable
        dt.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int)); //Creamos la columna Id del DataTable de tipo int
        dt.Columns.Add("Nombre", typeof(string)); //Creamos la columna Nombre del DataTable de tipo string
        dt.Columns.Add("Apellido", typeof(string)); //Creamos la columna Apellido del DataTable de tipo string

        // Una vez que el DataTable ha sido creado, utiliza la función NewRow() para crear un DataRow (es decir una fila).
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

        // Luego para agregar la nueva fila al DataTable, utilizamos la fila y el nombre de la columna.
        row["Id"] = 1;
        row["Nombre"] = "Juan";
        row["Apellido"] = "Pérez";
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: excelente, solo adapte y listo.

Answer (score 0):

generalmente se realiza con un iterador while

```
DataTable Dt = new DataTable(); 
while (readercoti.Read())                    
{
  Dt.Rows.Add(dr["nombreColumna1 o 21"].ToString(), (byte[])dr["nombrecolumna2 o 14"]);
 }
```

el array de bytes no se si esta bien casteado debes consultar un poco